# How to fetch results from mongodb aggregate with two matching fields

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to get the sum ratings of user admin from this JSON object:

```
{
            "_id": "5a7ef9a0ce8b5c00147c1ef3",
            "assessed_by": "admin",
            "rating": "Sad",
            "assessment_date": "2018-02-10T13:54:53.303Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a7efe6083fec3001465b369",
            "assessed_by": "admin",
            "rating": "Sad",
            "assessment_date": "2018-02-10T14:15:01.485Z"
        }
```

Expected output:

```
   {
    "_id" : "admin",
    "count" : 2.0
   }
```

I also wanted to sort the assessment_date by range so I used the $and operator but it doesn't seem to work on Node. I have my code here:

```
const now = moment().utc();
const endDate = moment().utc().subtract(9, 'days');
model.aggregate({ 
                $match: { 
                    $and: [
                        {rating: "Sad"}, 
                        {assessment_date: {$lte: now}},
                        {assessment_date: {$gte: endDate}}
                    ]
                } 
            }, { $group: 
                { _id: "admin", 
                count: { 
                    $sum: 1 }
                }
            }, function(err, results){
                console.log(results)                
            })
```

Mongo syntax seemed to work on Robomongo, but it doesn't work when trying on Node.

Comment: Does your query work without the date range filter i.e with just rating filter ?

Comment: @veeram Yes, it does! That's why I'm so confused

Comment: Okay. Is your date stored as string or date type ? Try `db.collectionname.find( { "assessment_date" : { $type : 9} } );` in robomongo

Comment: @veeram Yes, it is stored as Date type

Comment: Try `{                  $match: {rating: "Sad",                  assessment_date: {$lte: now, $gte: endDate}}                    }`

Comment: @veeram doesn't work on Node, but it works on Robomongo

Comment: @veeram the $match code you commented works on Robomongo, but didn't work on Node. Do you think the dates are the problem here?

Comment: no  I don't think so. you are sending string dates. Try `const now = moment();
const endDate = moment().subtract(9, 'days');`

Comment: Tried it, still returns an empty result

Comment: Can you please update your post with latest code ? The only other thing I can think of is UTC dates. Try `const now = moment().utc(); const endDate = moment().utc().subtract(9, 'days');`

Comment: Code updated with UTC dates, still empty result. Matching without date range works with this code `model.aggregate({ $match: { rating: "Sad" } }, { $group: { _id: "admin, count: { $sum: 1 }}}, function(err, result){
                console.log(result)
            })`

Comment: Can you try `model.aggregate({ $match: { rating: "Sad", assessment_date: {$gte: endDate}} }, { $group: { _id: "admin, count: { $sum: 1 }}}, function(err, result){ console.log(result) })` ? Also can you show how you are sending dates in robomongo ?

Comment: That's what the posted code looks like. It really returns an empty result

Comment: No,not really. It just has one side of date range filter. ( $gte part )

Comment: Tried it and still empty

Comment: Okay last try. Does this work ? `model.aggregate({ $match: { rating: "Sad", assessment_date: {$gte: "2018-02-09T13:54:53.303Z"}} }, { $group: { _id: "admin", count: { $sum: 1 }}}, function(err, result){ console.log(result) })` If this doesnt work I have no more ideas.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your robomongo query that worked for you ?

Comment: `db.getCollection('tickets').aggregate({ $match: { $and: [{rating: "Sad"}, {assessment_date: {$gte: ISODate("2018-02-02T00:00:00.303Z")}},{assessment_date: {$lte: ISODate("2018-02-11T13:54:53.303Z")}} ]} }, { $group: { _id: "admin", count: { $sum: 1 }}})`

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregation pipeline stages need to be in an array.

```
model.aggregate( [ { <stage> }, ... ] )
```